# "Request method 'POST' is not supported" when using @PutMapping(and @PatchMapping)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, httprequest

This is my administrator controller class with all methods but the problem I have is with `employeePartialEdit` method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;
    private final DepartmentService departmentService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AdminController(EmployeeService employeeService, DepartmentService departmentService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
        this.departmentService = departmentService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    @GetMapping("/homepage")
    public String showAdminPage(){
        return "admin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public String showEmployeeList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
        return "employeesListed";
    }

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public String showFindEmployeeByUsernameForm(){
        return "employeeFindByUsername";
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public String showEmployee(@RequestParam("username") String username, Model model){
        Optional<Employee> employee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException("Employee with username " + username + " can't be found.")));

        System.out.println("I'm in /employee");
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "displayEmployee";

    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{username}")
    public String showEditEmployeeForm(@PathVariable String username, Model model){
        System.out.println("I'm in /edit/{username} ");
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        return "employee-edit";
    }

    **@PutMapping("/edit")
    public String employeePartialEdit(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams){

        // still have to implement how to handle this..

        System.out.println("Parameters are: " + allParams.entrySet());

        System.out.println("I'm in employeePartialEdit method");

        return "redirect:/staff";
    }**

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String showAddEmployeeForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
        return "employeeAddForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee , BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        try {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
                model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
                model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
                return "employeeAddForm";
            }
            employee.setDateEmployed(LocalDateTime.now());
            employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employee.getPassword()));
            employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
            return "redirect:/admin/save";
        } catch (UsernameAlreadyExistsException ex) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getMessage());
            return "errorpage";
        }
    }
```

My Templates:
admin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="center">

        <h1>Admin Page</h1>

        <a href="/admin/save">Create Employee</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="/admin/employee">Find Employee By Username</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="/admin/employees">List all Employees</a>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

displayEmployee.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Employee Data</h2>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getUsername()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getEmail()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getRole()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getDepartment().getName()}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{/admin/edit/{username}(username=${employee.get.getUsername()})}">Edit</a></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **And here we get to the problem (I think). When I submit my post form from `employee-edit` I get the error from title, I don't really
> understand why it's saying POST since im trying to use PUT. I tried to
> change @PutMapping to @PostMapping and then I don't get the error(do I
> just use @PostMapping annotation..?). I can se the message printed
> out.**
>
> employee-edit.html where I have a form which (for now has only 2
> fields) has fields of Employee.model where I will enter new data so I
> can update the employee In here i also send username as hidden so I
> don't lose it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Edit Employee Info</h2>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/edit}" method="post" >
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="change last_name..">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="change first_name..">
            <input type="hidden" name="username" th:value="${username}" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also how's my approach of handling the code, please be critical...

Comment: You are trying to use REST conventions from an HTML form? Browsers normally only support GET and POST. Operations like PUT are for programmatic use. You see that form you wrote? `method="post"` means exactly that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused :/

Is using @PostMapping then a right way to go or should I change the whole approach?